# Can´t receive AppMessage from Pebble on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pebble-watch

On the Watch i send an AppMessage like this

```
DictionaryIterator *iter;
app_message_outbox_begin(&iter);
Tuplet value = TupletInteger(MESSAGE_TYPE, MESSAGETYPE_REFRESH);
dict_write_tuplet(iter, &value);
app_message_outbox_send();
```

I set the background modes and protocols for my app as described in [the tutorial](https://developer.getpebble.com/2/mobile-app-guide/ios-guide.html/).
In iOS i set the listeners like this:

```
[PBPebbleCentral defaultCentral].delegate = self;
self.watch = [PBPebbleCentral defaultCentral].lastConnectedWatch;

NSLog(@"Pebble name: %@", _watch.name);
NSLog(@"Pebble serial number: %@", _watch.serialNumber);

[_watch appMessagesAddReceiveUpdateHandler:^BOOL(PBWatch *watch, NSDictionary *update) {
    NSLog(@"Update received!");
    return YES;
}];

[_watch appMessagesAddReceiveAllUpdatesHandler:^BOOL(PBWatch *watch, NSUUID *uuid, NSDictionary *update) {
    NSLog(@"AllUpdate received!");
    return YES;
}];

[_watch appMessagesAddAppLifecycleUpdateHandler:^(PBWatch *watch, NSUUID *uuid, PBAppState newAppState) {
    NSLog(@"AppLifecycleUpdate received!");
}];
```

I already did send messages from the phone to the watch. So that way it works. But the listeners for incoming messages on the phone wont get called.
On the clock i get `APP_MSG_SEND_TIMEOUT` as error code. What did i wrong?

Comment: On the iOS side you need to connect to the pebble. have you done this?

Comment: Yes. I added the info to my question. I also sent messages to the phone successfully. But the other way around it does not seem to work.

Comment: Maybe you could share the full source on github or gist? This should work, I would like to see if I can reproduce this problem.

Comment: I solved it! In my case it seems that i registered the listeners too early. I tried to register them after i sent the launch message to the app, and that did the trick.
`[_watch appMessagesLaunch:^(PBWatch *watch, NSError *error) {
  [_watch appMessagesAddReceiveUpdateHandler:^BOOL(PBWatch *watch, NSDictionary *update) {
    // my code
  }
}];`
But why is that?

Comment: Not sure. would be interesting to see the code. Maybe the watch object was not ready yet?

Comment: As i´m struggling to get the project done i have no time to clean the code and post it right now. But i try to do so when it´s done.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have src/js/pebble-js-app.js in your watch app? I had the same problem and when i removed this generated file it started working.

Comment: No. This file dosen´t exist in my src or build folders.

Comment: @hi,could you explain more?how to start,where to start,where the communication being run?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you are using

```
appMessagesAddReceiveUpdateHandler:withUUID:
```

instead of

```
appMessagesAddReceiveUpdateHandler:
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to where you put the listener. For example if you are using the WeatherDemo app (provided by Pebble) you should do that after setting the the app UUID.

```
// Test if the Pebble's firmware supports AppMessages / Weather:
  [watch appMessagesGetIsSupported:^(PBWatch *watch, BOOL isAppMessagesSupported) {
    if (isAppMessagesSupported) {
      ...

        [_targetWatch appMessagesAddReceiveUpdateHandler:^BOOL(PBWatch *watch, NSDictionary *update) {
            NSLog(@"Received message: %@", update);

            return YES;
        }];
    } else {
....
```

Another thing to pay attention is not to put it under 
`- (void)pebbleCentral:(PBPebbleCentral*)central watchDidConnect:(PBWatch*)watch isNew:(BOOL)isNew`
because this function isn't called if the device is already connected.